# Python Saving File if a function is true

Tags: python, save

I am writing a save function; which writes a list to a new text file if functions are true. However it's not working as I expected. Currently it does not print anything when the save function is called.
The savedata function calls the duplicate function:

My "d" is a list like so:

[ 'ABB'
    'CAB'
    'BCA']

```
duplicate=[]
list=[]

def dup():
l=len(d)
for i in range(l):
    column.append([x[i] for x in d])
for col in column:
    for i in range(0,len(col)-1):
        if col[i] == col[i+1]:
            print(str(col[i]) + " is a duplicate in column " + str(column.index(col)+1) + " position(index) " + str(col.index(col[i+1])+1))
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Now when i print duplicate() KNOWING i do have duplicates in the list, it should return False, however it returns True. Why is this?

Comment: Your check `if duplicate == True` does not call the function, use `if duplicate() == True` instead. Also, is `d` globally defined? In your snipppet, `d` is undefined.

Comment: You have multiple problems but one is `if duplicate == True`. That didn't call the function it just tested whether the function object itself is True. Its not. Use `if duplicate():` instead.

Comment: Sorry; I should have put d aswell; d is a list defined at the top. I'm not receiving any errors.

Comment: Also why do you do have `elif` for `False`, could be a simple `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the function in your `if` condition, what it's actually checking for is if `duplicate` has been defined (in this case, yes, as a function).

Use `if duplicate():`. Also, I don't see where you're defining `d`. Perhaps that will raise an error.

Comment: Sorry; I should have put d aswell; d is a list defined at the top. I'm not receiving any errors. I also tried replacing with if duplicate(): but still no luck

Comment: What happened exactly when you replaced it with `duplicate()`? Were you able to identify where in the program the logic got twisted?

Comment: If i replace it with `duplicate()` it still does not print out any message; and its also making my duplicate function not work (i.e. it doesn't say where the duplicates are, which it did do initially)

Comment: I tried running the first part of your duplicate function. The program raises an `IndexError` at `cols.append([x[i] for x in d])` with `d = ['1', '2', '3']`.

Comment: Hmm, with my full code; i dont get any sorts of error? Could you be getting an error because you do not have the full code? Or is this something that's happening regardless?

Comment: I edited my code and took a different approach. Now the problem is, that the file is still saving even though there is a duplicate? Although it should only save if the `else` statement runs?

Comment: Where are you calling `duplicate()`? I suspect that you're making multiple calls to `duplicate()` and at least one of those calls go through the `else` statement, leading you to think that it is still saving.

If that is not the case, then I don't know. Assuming you're using the `print` statement in your code as a debugging checkpoint, it shouldn't enter the `else` clause anymore, especially since you `return` at the end of the `if` clause.

Comment: I call duplicate at the end of everything; so that the function runs. Hmm bit mind-boggled at the moment. I'll see what i can do. Thanks again

Comment: I updated the code and question slightly differently. Is this something you can understand? I dont quite understand why It keeps returning true.

Comment: What exactly are you storing in col? Strings? Integers? Also, the indentation is messed up in your example.